# Is the identifier in a for loop a variable?

Tags: python

Is the letter identifier considered a variable?

```
text = "Hello"
for letter in text:
    print(letter)
```

Comment: Yes `letter` is a variable !

Comment: correct. you can also check variable type for letter in text: print type(letter)

Comment: @Benjamin: regarding your suggested edit: do not add `code ticks` for things that are clearly not code. Most likely suggestions such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11664540) get rejected because of that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is considered a variable, within and even after the scope of the `for` loop:

```
text = ("hello")
for j in text:
    print(j)
print(j)
```

Output:

```
h
e
l
l
o
o
```

Comment: @benjamin see comment directed toward you above. If you want to emphasise a word, use italics (underscore) or bold (asterisk). Or, if you want to distinguish [use vs mention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use–mention_distinction) just use quotation marks.